# insmod error "unknown symbol in module"

Tags: linux-device-driver, insmod

I am writing parallel LED board driver, .ko is successfully generated.

I am facing this issue

> [63722.594233] led: Unknown symbol parport_register_device (err 0)
>
> [63722.594264] led: Unknown symbol parport_register_driver (err 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parport_register_device` is exported in [drivers/parport/share.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/parport/share.c?v=3.7#L1024). So you have to load parport driver first (`modprobe parport`) and then your driver.

Comment: I run command "modprobe parport" but i got error :  FATAL: Module parport not found.

Comment: Then you have to find it and load it! Look for drivers in /lib/modules `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name parport`

Then try to load it by actual name with `modprobe` or `insmod`.

Comment: What a simple solution after hours of desperation ;-)